# Other ways of doing this query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following tables:

```
Animals (animal_id, producer_id, ...)
Producers (prod_id, ...)
BoughtAnimals (animal_id (fk), ...)
```

and I'd like to make a query that tells me for each producer, how many animals it has, and how many of those animals were bought. After much thought, I tried the following approach:

```
select Producers.name, count (distinct A1.animal_id), count(distinct BoughtAnimals.animal_id)
from Producers, Animals A1, Animals A2, BoughtAnimals
where
  Producers.nif = A1.producer_id and
  Producers.nif = A2.producer_id and
  BoughtAnimals.animal_id = A2.animal_id
group by Producers.name;
```

but I did it only by trial and error, and I find it hard to reason about several Animal tables at once. Is there any other approach to make this query? Or is this the usual way of doing it?

Comment: You will understand how to do queries better if you stop using implicit syntax and learn about joins.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
select p.name,
    sum(case when ba.anyfield is not null then 1 else 0 end) bought_count,
    count(1) total_count
from Producers p join Animals a on (p.nif = a.producer_id)
    left join BoughtAnimals ba using (animal_id)
group by p.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple JOIN, you could then put the "COUNT" in a HAVING statement. See documentation for LEFT / INNER JOIN and HAVING, depending on your SGDB.

Comment: I don't understand how a HAVING statement will help anything in this. By what I've read, it seems a HAVING statement serves the purpose of limit the amount of rows that are returned, and that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ignoring the producers table for now; all the critical data you need is in the other two tables. Once this part is right, you can just do an inner join on the producers table to get the other details you need.

```
select a1.producer_id, 
       count(a1.animal_id) as num_animals, 
       count(b1.animal_id) as num_bought
from animals a1
left join boughtanimals b1 on (b1.animal_id = a1.animal_id)
group by producer_id;
```

It's not clear to me whether that last column is better named "num_bought" or "num_sold". Also not clear is what it means for a producer to "have" an animal, given that some animals are either bought or sold.